# Configuring the minicom serial port

Tags: linux

Actually i want to use minicom to run AT commands for my GSM modem (USB 2.0 FAX MODEM).

output of lsusb:-
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 17ef:602d Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0572:1300 Conexant Systems (Rockwell), Inc. SoftK56 Data Fax Voice CARP
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

and the output of dmesg:-
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[ 2933.978369] usb 2-1.1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0

The output of my assigned serial port is ttyUSB0.

So when i configure the serial port in minicom :-
serial port - /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud rate - 9600 8NI
Flow control - OFF
and then save the setting as dfl.
it says configuration saved.

But when i run "Sudo minicom" from mu ubuntu terminal :-

Welcome to minicom 2.6.2

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Feb  8 2013, 06:27:51.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 18:54:08

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

Oops - Its not giving me the cmd to write my at commands.

Any suggesstions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue with my Nokia N21 Modem and minicom. I just used utility called screen and only executed

sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600

and bingo !!

Cheers
Anuradha